# Find unique and common points in two sets in java without using any sets, lists etc

Tags: java, arrays, intersect

So my problem here is that I need to find intersects and differences in two sets that are given. Intersect is almost done, while it gives errors such as "required: int, found: oo.hide.Point" or "required: oo.hide.Point[], found: int[]". I cannot use any sets, lists or other built-in/dynamical collections. Is there any way to work those two methods out? 
I would be very thankful for the help.

``

Comment: What would you expect instead of *required: int, found: oo.hide.Point* ?  You're trying to add a `Point` object into an `int` array. Change the `int[] newPoints = new int[points]` to `Point[] newPoints = new Point[points]`

Comment: Hmm, everything seems to be working now with the intersect method, but still testing shows:
```java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <(1, 1), (1, 2)>
     but: was <(1, 1), (1, 2)>
Expected :is <(1, 1), (1, 2)>
Actual   :<(1, 1), (1, 2)>```

Comment: Have you overridden the `equals()` method ? Anyway, I'm assuming not since the code is correct but the result is wrong. You need to override the `equals()` method in `PointSet` class.

Answer (score 0):

I've told you in comments that you need to override the `equals()` method in order to make `assertThat` work properly. The way you overridden it is not correct, here is how you should write it:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    PointSet pointSet= (PointSet) o;
    return Arrays.equals(pointArr, pointSet.pointArr);
}
```

**PS:** Don't forget to override `equals()` in `Point` class too.

Comment: Added my answer to you :)

Comment: What does your `contains` method do ? From the line `other.contains(pointArr[i])`